# Control execution speed

Tags: jvm, interpreter, bytecode

I am thinking of making a "programming game", i.e. where each player writes a program to control their "bot", and then the programs are pitted against each-other to see who wins (by some definition of "win").

To make this fair, each bot program should execute at the same speed, so using native pre-compiled C/C++ code seems out of the question.

I can think of 3 options, but am unsure about 2:

1. **Use a language that runs in a VM** - This would mean that bots are written in Java and compiled to JVM bytecode. Then every bot gets a JVM and I would need to control the JVM "clock" or whatever it has to control the execution speed.
   ***Problem:*** Can the JVM "clock" be controlled, telling it to run *X* clock cycles worth of code?
2. **Use a scripting language** - Bots wuld be written in JS or Python or whatever.
   ***Problem:*** Same as above - can the speed be controlled?
3. **Use my own simplified language** -
   ***Problems:*** I am writing a game, not a compiler. It will mean anyone playing has to learn yet another language, which means no one will play.

---

So basically, I guess the question is can I control the execution speed of the JVM or some language interpreter (not in theory - in practice)? Or is there another option I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

The JVM isn't real-time, nor, I suspect is your OS. Relying on the JVM and/or process interactions isn't going to work since you're at the mercy of OS scheduling, JVM thread scheduling etc.

If you want to coordinate multiple threads, then you should look at the JVM thread model and in particular how to use [locks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html) to coordinate 2 threads.

Comment: That is why I said each bot would have it's own JVM. Than I could (if possible) tell each JVM in turn to execute, say, 100 instructions, and they would each do it at their own pace (depending on OS scheduling), but when each call returns each JVM has executed 100 instructions and is now "paused", simulating a constant running environment.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write your own JVM that you instrument to run only a fixed number of bytecode instructions from each program. Bytecode is a lot easier to digest that human-readable source code, so you could get away with relatively little implementation work, while your users would get to program in any programming language that can produce Java bytecode.

It gets easier if you institute some restrictions like "no threads" and "no try/catch". You'll need to implement a few core language features from `java.lang.*` plus some domain-specific I/O features, but for most of the rest of the JRE (for example `java.util.*`) you should be able to get away with executing bytecode from an existing JRE implementation (modulo legal constraints if you distribute the game engine).

Expect a slowdown of between 10x and 100x (depending on your implementation technology) compared to running on an off-the-shelf optimized JVM.

**Alternatively**, run an existing JVM in debug mode, single-step through the contestant programs with your game [pretending to be a debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture). Whether this is easier or harder than writing a bare-bones JVM yourself I'm not sure.